# How do I stabilize power to my PC from an erratic power supply?

Tags: electrical

An erratic power supply with low voltage particularly at night exists in my area (in India).The UPS tag tells a 220v/50Hz which I know not what. It does not tell about any amp marking. Can I use a voltage stabilizer for that ? If so of what kind or type?

Comment: You did not say if there was a problem with the equipment plugged into the UPS. Usually you can hear if the UPS is on battery backup. Do you hear that or does the UPS eventually power down if the battery is used? The UPS should have a VA rating (Volt-Amps) which can generally be used to determine the length of time the battery will last.

Comment: What is the UPS's VA or kVA rating?

Comment: Model MBI UPS A600
VA/W   600VA/360W
Input Voltage 230VAC
Voltage Range  140-300VAC
Frequency >40Hz(Auto Sensing)
Now my problem is when the voltage input becomes low the ups mode stars with beep sounds & after 10 minutes(approx) back-up it gets switched off. What I want is to regulate the input power supply to the UPS with a stabilizer (if that is possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a voltage stabilizer, but it makes little sense to do so.

Almost all UPSs are specifically designed to work with dirty power sources.  The UPS working range is probably as good, if not better, than any comparable stabilizer in the same power range and price class.

It would be more cost effective to replace the UPS with a model which has a wider input range than to add a stabilizer.  This also means there are half as many things to fail.

Comment: Perhaps an on-line UPS would be better. These convert the line voltage to DC, and then back to regulated AC.